# How do I highlight and save text in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to highlight text and save the selection so that next time I view the page, it will display with the same text highlighted.

I tried to get the index of selected text but the index is related only to the HTML tag, not related to all the page text. This is what I have:

```
<script>
    function highlight() {
       range = window.getSelection();
       var st = range.anchorOffset;
       var en = range.focusOffset - range.anchorOffset;
       alert(st);
       alert(en);
    }
</script>
```

I don't know how to get selected text attributes which can help me to save my highlight in the next open to the HTML file.

Comment: No I want to save highlight mode mean want to save the background color which i put it to the selected text.

Comment: Could you provide an HTML example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found. For reference, [here is a good post about this topic](http://mark.koli.ch/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwNy6/)

JS:

```
var copiedText = "";

$(function(){

    $("button").click(function(event){
        getSelectionText();
        alert(copiedText);
    });
});

function getSelectionText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        copiedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        copiedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to get the selected text i want to save my text highlight.that i want to highlight selected text then when i close the HTML file and open it again i want to load the highlighted color with it again because the normal highlight is removed as soon as i close the HTML file .